# Custom UINavigationBar's backButton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am making a iPhone app that allows the user to go back in a UINavigationBar. However, the way it looks now is horrendous. I am trying to customize it with my own image (minus the default UIBarButtonItem background). My image includes my custom background, but you can still see part of the button on the left and the right.

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_normal.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self   action:@selector(cancel:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

Is there a way to remove that space? Is there a possibility I can use a UIButton so I can customize it completely? I did something in interface builder where i dragged a UIButton into the UINavigationBar's rightButton and it works perfectly. Is there anyway I can do it programmatically?

Thanks!

Here's how it looks:

[image: UINavigationBar]

EDIT #1:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Here's how I make my background for the UINavigationBar (places in my RootViewController):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCustomDraw)

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

[self setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.85f green: 0.85f blue:0.85f alpha:1]];

if ([self.topItem.title length] > 0 && ![self.topItem.title isEqualToString:@"Back to ..."]) {
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBar_background.png"] drawInRect:rect];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 20.0];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = self.topItem.title;
    self.topItem.titleView = label;

} else {
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_button.png"] drawInRect:rect];
    self.topItem.titleView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
}
}

@end
```

Comment: possible duplicates: [How to create backBarButtomItem with custom view for a UINavigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526520/how-to-create-backbarbuttomitem-with-custom-view-for-a-uinavigationcontroller); [UINavigationBar back button skinning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053435/uinavigationbar-back-button-skinning); [How to change a UIBarButtonItem in a UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570247); from the **Related** sidebar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to add `UIButton` to navigation bar via obj-c, your code should look like this:

```
UIButton *button = /* initialize your button */

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Comment: `no '-button' method found` on this line: `UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] button];`

Comment: Thanks! The action works so I know it's there... But for some reason I can't see it... Maybe it's behind the bar or something? Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmm. In my answer I wrote `setRightBarButtonItem`... Did you replace it with `setLeftBarButtonItem` method?

Comment: Yes, does that change anything? I wanted this to replace my default backButton.I added code to my question with how I made my button.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I wanted to check if it's on the left :) Let me think, I'll reply you in a sec.

Comment: @Kashiv: Thanks! I have been stumped for hours on how to do this, so take your time :)

Comment: OK, I have a question. In which way do you make your custom UINavigationBar background?

Comment: Code posted in the question. Also, I tried removing it and I still can't see the UIButton.

Comment: Maybe `button.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, /*button_width*/, /*button_height*/);` will help?

Comment: Hehe, no problem! The "frame's curse" returns :P

Answer (score 14):

Combined the two answers and added the Back Button Functionality

```
// Custom Navigation Bar Back Button

// Create Button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,54,32); // width=54, height=32

// Set Button Image
NSString *backButtonURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"back" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backButtonURL];
[button setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Important: Set Button Action to go back
[button addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` instead `UIButtonTypeCustom`. You may also want to use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_normal.png"]
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
```