# Toolbar images, confusing

Tags: ios, menu, uinavigationbar

I have seen many apps that have navigation bars at the top of their app, and the left button is a button with 3 vertically stacked bars. I have seen this, and cannot find anything on it. It usually loads a whole side menu, and gives many options, can someone tell me what this button is, what it is used for, and how to use it? All advice is appreciated!

Comment: You can customise the buttons. This post has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003082/custom-uinavigationbars-backbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a standard button, but it links with some library like [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController). There are several options for which library to use if you search github or [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com).

Comment: This is exactly what i was talking about! Thanks for the information!